# 'Answered questions' filter for questions page

Tags: feature-request

Currently, the main questions page has a filter for unanswered questions - obviously, for the benefit of those with the expertise to answer such questions (or some of them).

I'm at the other end of the expertise spectrum: I'd like to filter for ANSWERED questions, because I'm looking to absorb the goodness from the answers!

Could TPTB consider tweaking the HTML, please?

Comment: Have you read the "advanced search tips" available from any search page? One option it provides is a search by minimum answer count, as in [answers:1](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=answers%3A1).

Comment: That's great - thanks. Just one thing: you only get to know that advanced search via tags is available when you search in the regular search box. Perhaps there should be a link next to the regular search box to info about the tags.