# Answered questions filter for tags page

Tags: feature-request

It is possible ([I discovered!](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1553/answered-questions-filter-for-questions-page)) to filter out unanswered questions from a search.

It doesn't seem to be possible to do the same when you pull up questions by clicking on a tag.

The question search URL uses a query string to which the 'answered' condition can be added with a '&'. The tag URL is static. (That exhausts the HTML expertise I can bring to bear on the problem!)

If my analysis is correct, is there a way of adding an answered filter to tag 'searches'?

Comment: (By the way, did you notice [the meta thread I posted](http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1554/how-should-a-new-user-navigate-cross-validated-to-learn-more-about-statistics) that was inspired by your last meta-Q? That might help you to navigate CV. Enjoy!)

Comment: Yes, I did - very helpful in negotiating the highways and byways of CV!

Answer (score 4):

To search under a tag, you can either click on the tag, or type `[<tag-name>]` in the search field.  Once you get to the search returns page, the *advanced search options* link appears with the guidelines for more sophisticated searches.  However, you don't need that link to appear on the page in order to use those options; from any old page you can type `[<tag-name>]+answers:1` in the search field to get all the threads tagged with that topic that have at least one answer.  For example, [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bclustering%5D%2banswers:1) are the questions tagged under clustering that have one or more answers.

Comment: Using _'+answers:1'_ in the search box works a treat - many thanks for that.

However - when I open up the main Tags page and click on the Regression tag, I get the URL http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/regression - ie, a static URL. And there is no _advanced search options_ link showing.

If enter _[regression]_ in any old search box, I get the same result.   

Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: Oops - hadn't realised HTML doesn't work in comments... Fixed

Comment: Entering `[regression]` in a search field is fine; you're not doing anything wrong there.

Comment: But - it brings up the page with the static URL and no 'advanced search options link'. So you can't filter for answered questions. The only way to do that (that I've found) is to add '+answers:1' to your other search terms in the initial search (as you suggested). Which is OK if you're 'in the know' or if you've read this page through, but not otherwise!